# How to download a base64 image in PHP from a web service?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, soap, base64

I admit I have a lot of trouble with this problem (I don't know much about PHP and SOAP.

I have to get product pictures for an ecommerce via a web service of a provider (SOAP).

As shown in the picture below, the product pictures are converted to base64.

[Example for a product picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhTYO.png)

I need to retrieve all the pictures to upload them in a folder on my site and write the path of each picture in a CSV file.

The code below allows me to retrieve all the products that are sent to me via the web service. I recover all the products with the function RecupEtatStock() then, with the help of a loop, for each product I search if there are images with the function RecupPhotoProduct().

```
    $wsdl       = "https://sinex-saas.com/B00UWSUG9Z34TN22/Services/WebServiceStandard.asmx?WSDL"; 
    $client     = new SoapClient($wsdl);
    $password   = "????";
    $username   = "????";
    $reffab     = 4;
    $codefab    = 2;
    $i          = 0;
    $fp         = fopen(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'file.csv', 'w+');
        
    $dataRecupererEtatStock     = RecupEtatStock($username, $password, $client);

    foreach ($dataRecupererEtatStock as $fields) {
        $dataRecupPhotoProduit  = RecupPhotoProduit($username, $password, $client, $fields->CodeFab, $fields->RefFab, $i);
        $fields->image          = $dataRecupPhotoProduit;

        fputcsv($fp, get_object_vars($fields));
        $i+=1;
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Here is what the RecupPhotoProduct() function looks like. If there is no picture, the function returns null, otherwise it retrieves what the save_image() function returns.

```
    function RecupPhotoProduit($pUsername, $pPassword, $pClient, $pCodeFab, $pReffab, $pi) {
        $optionsRecupererPhotoProduit = array(
            'user'      => $pUsername,
            'password'  => $pPassword,
            'codeFab'   => $pCodeFab,
            'refFab'    => $pReffab,
        );

        $responseRecupererPhotoProduit = $pClient->RecupererPhotoProduit($optionsRecupererPhotoProduit);
            
        $array = get_object_vars($responseRecupererPhotoProduit);
        if(empty($array)) {
            $responseRecupererPhotoProduit = null;
        } else {
            $responseRecupererPhotoProduit = $responseRecupererPhotoProduit->RecupererPhotoProduitResult;
            $responseRecupererPhotoProduit = save_image($responseRecupererPhotoProduit, $pi);
        }

        return $responseRecupererPhotoProduit;

    }
```

The above function allows me to retrieve the string in "RetrievePhotoProductResult" from this XML result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <RecupererPhotoProduitResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <RecupererPhotoProduitResult>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</RecupererPhotoProduitResult>
    </RecupererPhotoProduitResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So for this example, the MIME64 encoded text is :

```
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
```

And this is what my save_image() function looks like. It decodes the base64 image from the "RetrievePhotoProductResult" part of the previous XML and uploads it to my WordPress plugin directory.

```
    function save_image( $base64_img, $title ) {
        $base64_img     = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64_img);
        $base64_img     = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_img);
        $data           = base64_decode($base64_img);
        $file           = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . $title . '.png';

        return file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }
```

But here is my problem, the images download well in my directory. However, I can't open them.

For example, if I try to open them with Paint, this is what I get (Whether I open an image with Paint or not, it's the same thing. I think the problem is the base64 encoding):

> Paint cannot read this file. It is not a valid bitmap file or its format is not currently supported.

And if I want to access an image from my ecommerce site, I have a simple white dot that appears:

[I have a simple white dot that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7IOL.png)

And here is what the base64 string looks like after decoding:

[the base64 string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIGF5.png)

Do you know how I could download a base64 image via a php web service?

Comment: Try using an image viewer instead of `paint`?

Comment: Hi @barrycarter, thanks for your answer, but it's the same thing. The problem persists. I think the problem comes from the base64 encoding of the images that I can't decode correctly.

Comment: If it's not private, can we see a copy of the file you get?

Comment: If by "file" you mean an example of a product image. I can't upload it to Stack Overflow since the format doesn't seem right.

But to have an example of how to integrate a product image on e-commerce: https://bijouteriecourtois.fr/wp-content/plugins/soap-webee/173.png

Comment: OK, you are correct in saying that's not a PNG file. Now, could you post the MIME64 encoded text that produced that file?

Comment: Yes, of course. The string is too long so I updated the post above.

Comment: OK, when I base64 decoded that string, I got a 5260 byte JPG (not a PNG) image of a watch, so yes, your base64 decoding is the problem. Why `$base64_img = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_img);` (I think that's what breaking it)

Comment: This is an excellent question. To tell you the truth, I copied this part of the code from another post 

I tried to remove `$base64_img = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_img);` part and replace all PNGs with JPGs, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I've confirmed that replacing replacing spaces with pluses yields the bad file you're getting. Remove that line and try it again

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I still have exactly the same problem...

Comment: OK, could you show me the base64 string *after* you made that change?

Comment: Yes, I just added the image at the end of the post above to show you the base64 string after you made that change

Comment: Can you copy the SOAP response data (with base64 data) to a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) paste?

Comment: Hi @ProfessorAbronsius, yes : https://pastebin.com/SHAuZ78K

Comment: This is pending moderation, but I've already copied the data from the SOAP response (with the base64 data) into the above post in the "The above function allows me to retrieve the string in "RetrievePhotoProductResult" from this XML result:"

Comment: Just had a look at the image string and it is easily converted to an image of a wristwatch...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $encode = "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";
 $decode = base64_decode($encode);
 $size = getImageSizeFromString($decode);
 var_dump($size);
 if (empty($size['mime']) || strpos($size['mime'], 'image/') !== 0) {
    die('Base64 value is not a valid image');
  }

  $ext = substr($size['mime'], 6);
  $img_file = "filename.{$ext}";
  file_put_contents($img_file, $decode);

echo $ext;
?>
```

this will work for all valid images.

Comment: I think I just found my problem: when I retrieve the MIME64 encoded text string from the Web Service, it displays strangely.

I can't get it in this form (/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA ... 2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHB).

I get it back in a strange form (the last picture of my publication).

So I think my problem is in the code that allows me to get the base64 string from the web service:

`$responseRecupererPhotoProduit = $pClient->RecupererPhotoProduit($optionsRecupererPhotoProduit);
$responseRecupererPhotoProduit = $responseRecupererPhotoProduit->RecupererPhotoProduitResult;`